# Java set this to super argument

Tags: java, class, super

I am currently developing a game in Java and I have the following code:

```
public class Game extends Thread {
    public String name = "randomName";
    public int state=0;

    public GameLoop gameLoop;

    public Game(){
        gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    }

    public void run(){ // when the thread starts
        name="UpdatedName";
    }
}


public class GameLoop extends Game{

    public GameLoop(Game game){

        System.out.println(game.name); //UpdatedName
        System.out.println(name); // randomName, I want UpdatedName here!

    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to use "name" instead of game.name in the GameLoop class. Is this possible by anyway, my best guess is the super() command but not sure how to set it up, tried the following without much luck:

```
public class Game extends Thread {


    public String name = "randomName";
    public int state=0;

    public GameLoop gameLoop;

    public Game(Game game){
        this = game;
    }

    public Game(){
        gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    }

    public void run(){ // when the thread starts
        name="UpdatedName";
    }
}

public class GameLoop extends Game{

    public GameLoop(Game game){
        super(game);
        System.out.println(game.name); //UpdatedName
        System.out.println(name);  too!

    }

}
```

Am I missing something or is this not possible? The only reason for doing this is to make the code itself cleaner. Only solution I could come up with is:

```
 public class Game extends Thread {

    public String name = "randomName";
    public int state=0;

    public GameLoop gameLoop;

    public Game(Game game){
        name = game.name;
        state = game.state;
        // ...
    }

    public Game(){
        gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    }

    public void run(){ // when the thread starts
        name="UpdatedName";
    }
}
```

Which might work but is very ugly since I have many variables. Thanks for any help!

PS: Sorry for the misleading title, I'm not really sure what to call it!

Comment: A) I dont really understand what you intend to do B) your question is probably too broad. Basically you would an experienced person sitting down with you and talking about your thoughts ... and about solutions to that ... for hours. Maybe you can step back and first tell us what that `name` is supposed to do for you. You see - having a field in a class that *other* classes can directly read or write is a bad idea in the first place....

Comment: It sounds like `name` should be accessed through a getter, not a field, and the implementation for `GameLoop` should just delegate to the `game` object.

Comment: since gameloop extends game, the public instance variable name is available and should be accessible by that name.  what problem are you seeing?  using super is superfluous; as suggested above, it may be safer to use a getter as opposed to a public variable

Comment: If it's an extended object a getter is unnecessary

Comment: Your inheritance doesnt really make any sense. Also you should consider implementing `Runnable` interface as opposed to extending `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:  you need to fix the way you are doing these classes.

You have `GameLoop` extending `Game`, which means that any `GameLoop` is also a `Game` itself.  You have an instance of `GameLoop` in your `Game` class, which you set to a new `GameLoop` in the constructor.  But `GameLoop` is a `Game`, so when you create a new `GameLoop`, you're creating a new `Game`, which calls the constructor, which creates another one... it's an infinite loop of creating new objects, and the result, eventually, is a `StackOverflowError`.

You need to decide:  is a `GameLoop` a type of `Game`?  Or is a `GameLoop` something that a `Game` has?  (Or, maybe, is a `Game` something that a `GameLoop` has?)  If a `GameLoop` is something that a `Game` has, but isn't a `Game`, then `GameLoop` shouldn't extend `Game`.  If a `GameLoop` actually is a type of `Game`, then `GameLoop` and `Game` probably shouldn't contain references to each other.

Anyway, that doesn't really answer the question, so I'll try to do that.  If you really dislike using `game.name` in most of your code, one alternative is to use a method.

```
private String name()
{
    return game.name;
}
```

Now, in the rest of the class, you can use `name()` instead of `game.name`.  I'm really not sure why you would want to do things this way, though.  And the whole thing might become unnecessary once you rethink how your classes relate to each other.